# Remove segments and replaces in url with regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regular-language

I've this exercise:

Having these links

```
1. http://example.com/cat1/subcat3/subcat4/tag/this%20is%20page/asdasda?start=130
2. http://example.com/cat1/subcat3/subcat4/tag/this%20is%20pageasdasd
3. example.it/news/tag/this%is%20n%page?adsadsadasd
4. http://example.com/tag/thispage/asdasdasd.-?asds=
5. http://example.com/tag/this%20is%20page/asdasd
6. /tag/this/asdasdasd
7. /tag/asd-asd/feed/this-feed
8. /tag/sd-asd
```

- In first case the result must be: `http://example.com/tag/this%20is%20page`
- In second case the result must be: `http://example.com/tag/this%20is%20pageasdasd`
- In third case the result must be: `example.it/tag/this%is%20n%page`
- In forth case the result must be: `http://example.com/tag/thispage`
- In fifth case the result must be: `http://example.com/tag/this%20is%20page`
- In sixth case the result must be: `/tag/this`
- In seventh case the result must be: `/tag/asd-asd`

But eighth **must be not consider** by regex. The same is for domain name.

I tried to make it: https://regex101.com/r/aB5mPn/5 but i'm not able to not consider the last case.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Your regex looks to be working well. What exactly is your problematic for the last case?

Comment: Hello! Just not consider that case 

Comment: Doesn't "*not consider*" mean "*don't change stuff on it*" ? Or is it you should completely erase it ? If the first, then your regex seems fine, else, I don't see the logic behind

Comment: @Rafalon As you can see the domain name, does not considered from regex (not match). The same should be for last case.

Comment: "*As you can see the domain name, does not considered from regex*" - what ? Was this google translated ?

Comment: "_As you can see, the regex doesn't catch domain name. The same should be for last case._" Now is better?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see the difference between 7 and 8, and event though you catch the 8th case, you replace it with itself, so the result is the same as domain name, isn't it ?

Comment: @Rafalon The seventh has segments after that in front of "tag". Instead the last case has nothing after. Anyway by regex, the domain name never catched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you could add a negative lookahead before matching /tag...etc to assert that what follows for the eight case is not /tag/sd-asd until the end of the string `(?!\/tag\/[^\/]+$)`

Your regex could look like:

[`(?:(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?)+(?!\/tag\/[^\/]+$)(\/tag\/[A-Za-z0-9-%]+)(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/aB5mPn/6)

Comment: Best! Thank you!

Comment: Even if it works, I see no added value using that regex. It adds a lot more backtracking just to prevent one identity replacement?

Comment: @The fourth bird if i add more string, the regex doesn't work anymore: [link](https://regex101.com/r/aB5mPn/7). As you can see, third last now match and the last, not.

Comment: @Kouga That is because the lookahead checks if it is at the end of the string, and by adding content this will not be the end of the string anymore. What you could do it use anchor for the beginning `^` and the end of the line `$`. For example: 
[`^(?!\/tag\/[^\/]+$)(?:(?:https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+)?(.*(?=\/tag))(\/tag\/.*?(?=\/?))([\/?].*$)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/bNh6v9/1/) The part starting with `/tag/untilthefirstforwardslash` will be in group 2. The part that excludes `/tag/sd-asd` at the start of the string is inside a negative lookahead in the beginning: `(?!\/tag\/[^\/]+$)`

Comment: @The fourth bird Now instead you match also `http://example.com`. Furthermore `http://example.com/tag/this%is` or `http://example.com/tag/this-is` must not match. In summary, i need to get `/tag/<segment>` only if this pattern is preceded AND / OR followed by other segments without matching domain name, seems like your preceded answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird [link](https://regex101.com/r/aB5mPn/8) like this but last three test string must not be considered!

Comment: @Kouga Do you need to keep all the current selections and groups or do you need just 1 selection? What are you trying to accomplish? If your regex engine supports \K, you could use [`(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9-%]+\K)\/tag\/[A-Za-z0-9-%]+|\/tag\/[A-Za-z0-9-%]+(?=\/[A-Za-z0-9-%]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/BLtmkp/1). You could capture those in a [named captured group](https://regex101.com/r/K6rGCh/1). Or you could try it [like this](https://regex101.com/r/Loq3uI/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird last one si almost perfect! If i call `${tag}` group, in Match 2 and 3 i get also previous segment, as you can see: [link](https://regex101.com/r/Loq3uI/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird i tried to remove the previous segment to the one with `/tag/segment` from `${tag}` group but I can not :')